# Container transform gives missing image parameter error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerrun.aws.json

While I was trying to convert Docker compose file with the [container transform](http://container-transform.readthedocs.org) I got the following error:

```
Container "container-name" is missing required parameter 'image'.
```

Services with the image parameter, it operates fine. However, the ones with the build parameter instead of the image cause error. I want to build some of the images based on a Dockerfile by using a build parameter and I don't need an image parameter in the Docker compose file at all. What would be the most effective solution here?

Here is an example:

Successfull transformation for `db` service:

*Docker-compose.yml:*

```
db:
 image: postgres
```

*Dockerrun.aws.json:*

```
 "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "essential": true,
            "image": "postgres",
            "memory": 128,
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "containerPath": "/var/lib/postgresql/data/",
                    "sourceVolume": "Postgresql"
                }
            ],
            "name": "db"
        }
```

Unsuccessfull transformation for `web` service since `build` used instead of `image` parameter:

*Docker-compose.yml:*

```
web:
 build: 
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear what's the issue here, can you post a full dokcer-compose file which gives an error and the whole error message.

Comment: @ruohola Error message is already in the question from container transform and I appended more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that an AWS ECS (=elastic container service) task definition cannot depend on a Dockerfile to build the image. The image has to be already build for it to be used in a task definition. For this reason the `"image"` key is required in a task definition json file and so it has to be in the docker-compose file you are converting from also.

The image for the task definition can come from Docker hub (like the `postgres` image does) or you can build your own images and push them to AWS ECR (=elastic container registry).